# How to implement this example of plotly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plotly

The following example of plotly:
https://plot.ly/javascript-graphing-library/range-slider/

I want to use it to write a webpage, plotting some data and support adding notes by clicking, just as shown by the example in the url above.
The problem is I don't know how to implement it. Only the code for the function is provided and I don't know how to run it. I copy them into a html file but see nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to have a look at basic html and javascript first.
After that check out the getting started page of plotly.js: [Getting started](https://plot.ly/javascript/getting-started/)

It shows you two different ways on how to include the ploty.js lib on your website and it also provides a HelloWorld example which is a good starting point if you are interested in plotly.js

Nevertheless without any provided code which shows what you tryed to do it is hard to help you. But it seems your problem is basic html and js, so start by learning the basics first.